# Exact solution for an exponential equation involving powers

Tags: exponential-function, elementary-functions

A student asked me this exercise of a past exam:

> Find the smallest solution to the equation: $$\exp(\sqrt{2x})=16x^3-1.$$
> Give the anwser up to $4$ decimal places.

Is there a way to find an exact solutions? I tried to substitute $y=\sqrt{2x}$, obtaining the equation $e^y=2y^6-1$ but that leads to nothing. Also tried a bunch of other substitutions that don't work.

I believe that this equation cannot be solved exactly using elementary methods, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You are right to think there is no closed form solution using elementary methods.

Comment: Writing up the summation formula for $e^y$ yields the polynomial equation

$$2+y+\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^3}{6}+\frac{y^4}{24}+\frac{y^5}{120}+y^6\left(\frac{1}{720}-2\right)+O(y^7) = 0$$

Using numerical methods you can solve this to get $y \approx 1.12638$ and $x \approx 0.63436$.

But I don't think there is an elementary soltuion without using numerical methods.

Comment: @DanielP - The $O(y^7)$ tells you  that's an approximate solution.

Comment: Yup, exactly. It would actually continue with $\sum_{k=7}^{\infty} \frac{y^k}{k!}$, which will get really small due to the $k!$ coefficients.